# Equivalent to filter?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm playing FTB direwolf20 and I'm setting up a storage-system with a router and some barrels.

I've watched plenty of tutorials on how to do this efficiently, but they all use a filter (from RedPower 2) to pull out stacks of items (instead of pulling items one-by-one).

The problem is that my version of direwolf20 (1.5 v2 v1.1.3) doesn't have the filter.

Is there some other way of extracting full stacks of items from chests? Or am I doomed to use wooden pipes and engines to pull them out one-by-one?

Comment: a more powerful engine will pull out stacks at a time

Answer (score 1):

Itemducts. That's pneumatic tubes #2, and, it has a built-in extractor with just the use of a pneumatic servo and a wrench.  No timers nor engines required - thus less lag generated compared to any pipe system.  No spills either.  Best sorting system tool ever!

It can be set to have a whitelist/blacklist which let you deny any cobblestone going into the macerator along with ores (and by default no item will go to the macerator if it can't be processed by it).

It also has guidance options (red/green color) which means the colored pipe will be avoided/preferred.  If there are no colors, there will be equal distribution regardless of the differences in distance to the destinations.

Comment: Based on [this](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Pneumatic_Tube) wiki-page, It appears that I still need a filter/transposer to pull out items from the chest (still, I can only use transposer which pull out one item at a time). Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: Pneumatic tubes are like that. Itemducts, as I stated, don't require any other blocks to extract stuff. The pneumatic servo serves that purpose now.